# Data source name not found and no default driver specified (using Amazon Redshift (x64))

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
private OdbcConnection _internalConnection;
        public OdbcConnection InternalConnection
        {
            get
            {
                if (_internalConnection == null)
                {
                    Open();
                }
                return _internalConnection;
            }
        }

        public void Open()
        {
            _internalConnection = new OdbcConnection(CreateConnectionString());

            try
            {
                if (_internalConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    _internalConnection.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private string CreateConnectionString()
        {

            int endpointPort = 5439;

            string driver = "{Amazon Redshift (x64)}";
            string connectionString = "Driver={0};Server={1};Database={2};UID={3};PWD={4};Port={5};SSL=true;Sslmode=Require";

            connectionString = string.Format(connectionString,
                driver,
                Parameters[ConnectionParameterType.DataSource],
                Parameters[ConnectionParameterType.DatabaseName],
                Parameters[ConnectionParameterType.UserName],
                Parameters[ConnectionParameterType.Password],
                endpointPort);

            return connectionString;
        }
```

[see error in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezEah.png)

Comment: Try running a 32 bit version of your app. Drivers are bit dependant.

Comment: still same error found.

Comment: Have you verified that the driver you are trying to use is installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

install 32 bit driver

https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/AmazonRedshiftODBC32-1.3.1.1000.msi

and replace string driver with

string driver = "{Amazon Redshift (x86)}";

Comment: So I was on the right track then - needed 32 bit and the driver was missing. Well done.